# Swift Charts with Custom Symbol Shapes

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, charts, symbols

The following code tries to show two points with different symbols. The first one has a custom shape. The code causes the error **No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'**. Replacing **.symbol(point.symb)** with **.symbol(CustomTriangle())** shows both points with the custom symbol, indicating that **CustomTriangle** struct is okay.

There are two .symbol modifiers in **Charts** framework and the one returning a **ChartContent** (not a View) is essential for chaining other chart content modifiers. Is there a way to show the first point with the custom triangle while the next one with the square symbol?

Here is the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Point: Identifiable {
    public let id = UUID()
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
    let symb: any ChartSymbolShape
}


public struct CustomTriangle: ChartSymbolShape {
    
    public var perceptualUnitRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    
    public func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}


struct MyPlot: View {
    
    let points = [Point(x: 0, y: 0.5, symb: CustomTriangle()),
                  Point(x: 1, y: 1.0, symb: .square)]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(points, id: \.id) {point in
                PointMark(x: .value("xaxis", point.x),
                          y: .value("yaxis", point.y))
                .symbol(point.symb)  // this works --> .symbol(CustomTriangle())
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyPlot()
        .padding()
    }
}
```